# Error in svelte.config.js Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I setting up `svelte.config.js` like code below:

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const config = {
  preprocess: preprocess(),
};

export default config;
```

Suddenly, my Svelte codes keep getting error `Error in svelte.config.js SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

How to fix this issue? But I still be able to run the project using npm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're likely not using `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, so import statements don't work in `svelte.config.js`. You have three ways to fix this:

- Use `require()` instead (also see https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/in-general.md#generic-setup)
- Rename `svelte.config.js` to `svelte.config.mjs`
- Set `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` (may break other scripts)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by setting up **Svelte Language-server: Runtime on VSCode**

Go to `File > Preferences > Settings` search `svelte` in searchbox, then find `Svelte > Language-server: Runtime`

After that, add full path `node.exe` (e.g: `C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe`) to `Svelte > Language-server: Runtime`

Answer (score 0):

`npm i svelte-preprocess` in the terminal fixed it in my case (and got Tailwind working which is what I was trying to do).